# Tomcat Jersey throws 404

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx

Currently I'm facing the problem with one of our api's that we receive 404 (Not Found) directly from Tomcat. The thing is that the response is empty - so it wasn't thrown by our application, also our log is completely clean. Also it doesn't appear only on one path - it is appearing on different parts of the api - some are working and some of them not.

After restarting the our tomcat the response is as expected. It's a (for me) a completely random appearing problem, also for our IT team. May somebody face similar problems or maybe there is also a solution for this?

**Tomcat-Version:** Tomcat 7.0.39
**Java-Version:** 1.7.0-25
**NginX:** 1.4.7

Update: We are currently working with a hotdeploy on that server - may that could create these problems?

Comment: facing the same problem!

Comment: Similar problems appearing on our system too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a strange behavior on hotdeploy - after redeploy some references are not really cleared and so it points to a different part of the storage. After debugging a lot a simple restart will fix that issue - hopefully it will be fixed in a future version of tomcat - can't find a problem with our application at all - because also with a simply hello world with fileuploads (to achieve a lot of connections) I face the same issue - sometimes.